# Using Selenium in PowerShell, cannot capture dropdown

Tags: powershell, selenium

I have been attempting to automate a web page (help desk form) in PowerShell with the Selenium module. I can get all different types of elements except dropdowns. I have inconsistently been able to get some of them by doing a Find-SEElement and using the -xPath, performing a click() and then doing a Find-SEElement *again* on the resultant drop down list, but this does not always work. The one I am working on at the moment looks like this:

```
$User = Find-SeElement -Driver $chrome -Timeout 30 -XPath "//span[@id='control-wrapper-mainForm-GroupBoxDesignerControl4']//tr[1]//td[2]"
```

I can confirm that I do find the element, but if I try to do anything except click on it I get the "element is not interactable" error. I was reading through some other forums, and someone suggested doing something like this:

```
$User = Find-SeElement -Driver $chrome -Timeout 30 -XPath "//span[@id='control-wrapper-mainForm-GroupBoxDesignerControl4']//tr[1]//td[2]"
$Value = 'Joe Smith'
$SelectElement = [OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement]::new($User)
$SelectElement.SelectByValue($Value)
```

When I run this, however, I get the error "Element should have been select but was td". Googling this I have seen a number of threads and solutions for other languages such as Python and C#, but nothing specific to PowerShell. I am just looking for a consistent syntax to be able to grab a dropdown menu and select an item from the resultant list.

Comment: `SelectElement` is for `<select>` tag only, `User` has an element with `<td>` tag. You need to click the dropdown to open it and than click again on the option you want to select.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As mentioned, I can do something like $User.Click() or Invoke-SeClick -Element $User -Driver $chrome, and this works just fine. How I click on a name in that list is what is eluding me. I have tried Send-SEKeys, as the cursor is in that element, but to no avail. There does not seem to be a .SelectByValue method right on the SEElement.